# consider the mobius transformation $f(z) =\frac{1}{z} $ , $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $z \neq 0$.choose the correct options

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

consider the  mobius transformation  $f(z) =\frac{1}{z} $  , $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $z \neq 0$. If C  denotes  a circle  with positive radius  passing through the  origin, then  $f$ map  $C \setminus \{0\}$ to

choose the correct options

$1.$Circle

$2.$ a line

$3.$ a  line passing  through the  origin

$4.$ a  line   not passing  through the  origin

My attempt :  i take  $z = e^{i\theta}$,$f(z) = 1/z  = 1/e^{i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}$

that $f(z)  =  \cos\theta  - i\sin\theta$

After that im  not  able  to proceed  further pliz help me

any hints/solution will be appreciated thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of taking $z=e^{i\theta}$ that gives you a circle **not** passing through the origin? If you do take a circle passing through the origin, then what you will get is a line not passing through the origin. That is, the third option is the right one.

Comment: im not getting  @Jose  carlos  sir ....can u  elaborate more,,,,,\

Comment: Don't you get that your circle doesn't pass through the origin?

Comment: my confusion  is that  why  its  is not map circle  to circle ?

Comment: It maps **your** circle into a circle, but since your circle doesn't pass through the origin, that does not mapr. Now, comput$$f\bigl(\{e^{i\theta}+1\,|\,\theta\in[0,2\pi]\}\bigr)$$and see what you get then.

Comment: thanks  u @ Jose carlos sir i  understand now

Comment: But ur winter cap  is   beautiful !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It matches my eyes, doesn't it?! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the above Möbius transformation $f$ on the extended complex plane $\hat{\mathbb C} =\mathbb C \cup\{ \infty\}$ with $f(0)= \infty$ and $f(\infty)=0$.

Since $0 \in C$ we have $ \infty \in f(\hat{\mathbb C})$. And since $f(\infty)=0$, we see that the third option is correct.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to show that $A(x^2+y^2)+Bx+Cy+D=0$ under $\frac1z$ goes to $D(u^2+v^2)+Bu-Cv+A=0$

So as the circle does not pass through the origin, $A$ and either $B$ or $C$ are non-zero and $D=0$

Hence, options 2 and 4 true.